# Can't line up icons for jquery ui accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I can't get the icons to line up with the text here is the fiddle: [jquery accordion](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/kZkTV/1/)

I am happy with the rest of the code just need to line the icons up, I have tried targeting the span tags created with the icon in by jquery with no avail am I missing something.

Comment: Check out my answer. You need to remove the block display and left padding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `display: block` to `display: inline-block` here:

```
#helpmenu h3 a {  padding-right: 5px; color: #666; display: inline-block;  padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-decoration: none; padding-left: 18px;}
```

And also remove the `padding-left`. Also, use this for IE 7 compatibility:

```
*display: inline; *zoom: 1; /* Display Inline Block in IE 7 */
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZkTV/3/

Comment: Inline block doesn't work as expected in all browsers. You should be carefull with it.

Comment: @RJD22: I have added the compatibility for `inline-block`. Please check. :) And I just checked it with IE 7, IE 8, IE 9, FF 12, GC 19!

Comment: Sorry I can't get it to work in the IE 7, where does the IE 7 hack go?

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe Its `*display: inline; *zoom: 1;` Please see the answer fully!

Comment: I saw that but I can't where you put it in the css

Comment: Just put it next to `display: inline-block;` Finally, the full CSS should look like: `display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;`

Comment: It doesn't work in the website I am working on not sure why?, works in IE 8 etc just not 7

Comment: Can you please ping the site, May I inspect it once?

Comment: Is there a way of doing that privately

Comment: What happens in IE 7? Can you describe it?

Comment: The Icons aren't visible, I am using IE developer tools to test. It all works fine IE 8 -9 and all other browsers

Comment: Good! In that case, atleast show the full line of `#helpmenu h3 a` class definition please... Is it working fine in the fiddle?

Comment: #helpmenu h3 a {  padding-right: 5px; color: #666;  padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;} its not working in this fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/kZkTV/7/

Comment: Anyone have a cross browser solution to this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have done some testing and can see that the icons not showing in IE 7 is caused by something else I reverted back to my original code and they are not showing either. I am not sure what causes this

Comment: Try putting `zoom: 1;` to the `#helpmenu h3 span` and check it out. You need that to work... :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kZkTV/2/

I changed the `#helpmenu h3 a` to `display: inline-block` instead and added `vertical-align: middle`.  This should work unless you need to support very old IE versions.

You may also want to do some small updates to the padding here or there, especially to `:first-child` (a CSS2 pseudo-class).

Answer (score 0):

You should float the icons left. That way they won't influence the a.
http://jsfiddle.net/kZkTV/4/

```
.closedacc { background: url(http://www.somesite.com/dataimages/static/faq/menuarrow-blue.jpg) no-repeat 0 9px; padding-top: 2px; padding-botttom: 2px;  padding-left: 18px; float: left; width: 16px; height: 16px;}
```